# symbol table local static variable name

Tags: c, compilation, symbols

Why is there a number added to the name of a local static variable in the symbol table?

```
int main(void) {
    static stat_var = 20;

    return 0;
}
```

8: 0000000000000008     4 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT    2 stat_var**.1604**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There can be many local static variables with the same name (across different functions). The compiler is giving them disambiguating suffixes to avoid a potential name collision.

Comment: As a follow up, would you know how is this number generated?

Comment: @Akeel It's compiler specific. My guess is that they are generated per scope by the lexer. Looks from the symbol that it's gcc's implementation you're looking at so the source should be available.