# Why symbol table contains no variable name?

Tags: c++, variables, clang++, symbol-table

Create a `main.cpp` like this:

```
int main() {
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = a + b;
  int d = c % b;
  int e = c + d;  
  return e;
}
```

Compile it:

```
clang++ -g -O0 main.cpp
```

Then try to see the symbol table:

```
dsymutil -s a.out
```

Output looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Symbol table for: 'a.out' (arm64)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Index    n_strx   n_type             n_sect n_desc n_value
======== -------- ------------------ ------ ------ ----------------
[     0] 00000001 64 (N_SO         ) 01     0000   0000000000000000
[     1] 0000001c 64 (N_SO         ) 00     0000   0000000000000000 '/Users/<username>/tmp/'
[     2] 0000002f 64 (N_SO         ) 00     0000   0000000000000000 'main.cpp'
[     3] 00000038 66 (N_OSO        ) 00     0001   0000000065ef7009 '/private/var/folders/75/7ln8mr3j3md23mts9rq7jmcw0000gn/T/main-bf85b7.o'
[     4] 00000001 2e (N_BNSYM      ) 01     0000   0000000100003f4c
[     5] 00000016 24 (N_FUN        ) 01     0000   0000000100003f4c '_main'
[     6] 00000001 24 (N_FUN        ) 00     0000   000000000000005c
[     7] 00000001 4e (N_ENSYM      ) 01     0000   0000000100003f4c
[     8] 00000001 64 (N_SO         ) 01     0000   0000000000000000
[     9] 00000002 0f (     SECT EXT) 01     0010   0000000100000000 '__mh_execute_header'
[    10] 00000016 0f (     SECT EXT) 01     0000   0000000100003f4c '_main'
```

None of the variables are in the symbol table. I wonder why.

Thought about these:

- Maybe the variables are optimized away because the logic in the code is too simple. - But I gave `-O0` flag which means no optimization.
- Maybe the symbol table is never meant to have variable names. - Searched online and it seems variable names is expected to be in symbol tables.

So I'm out of guesses. Also tried to search stackoverflow for similar questions, didn't see any on the first page of search results. Sorry if this is a dupe.

Comment: Global variable names are expected, not local ones.

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks! It seems that local static variables are also expected (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907225/symbol-table-local-static-variable-name).

Comment: A non-`static` local variable is typically just an offset added to the stack pointer or a register, but your milage may vary (especially on the rare stackless systems).

Comment: Local variables don’t have fixed addresses, and indeed can have multiple addresses at the same time, which static symbol tables cannot express adequately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Symbol names exist for the purpose of linking one library or compilation unit to another.  Local variables are not visible over library or compilation unit boundaries.  So they never get anywhere close to the symbol table.

Global variables, function names, and some utility stuff like thread local initialization or virtual function table initialization are possible things to end up in symbol tables.  Even then it will depend on details of your execution environment.

For debugging purposes, debug information detailing the type and name of stack offsets inside functions can be generated: but that isn't part of the symbol table.